# PropertyChangedEventHandler How to get value?

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged

So I've setup the event to a class

```
    void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

And it's fired when a class's property gets changed, however I want to make the same change in a similar class. Take this as an example

```
class A: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   //event handler declaration

   string PhoneNumber;

   string _name;
   Public string Name {
     get { return _name;}
     set { _name = value; PropertyChanged("Name");}
   }
}

class B
{
   string Name;
   int age;
}
```

and the event binding for class A;

```
    void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

what I want is to copy the content of the Name property of A and assign it to an instance of B.

What is the elegant way to do that? My problem is knowing which value of A has changed(in my class it's not only name, but more).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [PropertyName attribute of the PropertyChangeEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs.aspx) to figure out which property was modified, then use some logic to set that property to, what I'm calling, the `boundItems`.

You can use the sender object and cast it to the appropriate type if you need to as well, this allows for a bit more flexibility. Using `Reflection` will allow you to get and set the property with no real manual labor involved by just using the `String` value of the `PropertyName`, but it's much more overhead, so if you're doing this a lot, I'd advise against it.

```
void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "Name":
            //You Code
            boundItem.Name = (sender as A).Name;
            break;
    } 
}
```

Alternatively, you can use Reflection to set the property instead of building a switch case.

```
void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Untested Reflection example. Probably needs some modifying. 
    PropertyInfo prop = typeof(A).GetType()
              .GetProperty(e.PropertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    PropertyInfo boundProp = typeof(B).GetType()
              .GetProperty(e.PropertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    boundProp.SetValue (boundItem, prop.GetValue((sender as A),0), null);
}
```

You best option, though, is to create the classes with these ties built into the object's properties. Modify the `get` and `set` of the properties to set both the affected property and the `boundItems` property as well. That would look like this:

```
class A: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   string PhoneNumber;
   string _name;
   B BoundItem = null;
   Public string Name {
     get { return _name;}
     set 
     { 
         _name = value; 
         if(BoundItem != null)
              BoundItem.Name = value;
     }
}

class B
{
   string Name;
   int age;
}

class Main
{
     public Main()
     {
         A item = new A();
         B boundItem = new B();
         item.BoundItem = boundItem;
         item.Name = "TEST";
         Console.WriteLine("Item Name: " + item.Name);
         Console.WriteLine("BoundItem Name: " + boundItem.Name);

         // Result:
         // Item Name: TEST
         // BoundItem Name: TEST
     }
}
```

Comment: Well you would then just say "bounditem.Name = (sender as B).Name" in the switch case. Alternatively, you can use Reflection to accomplish this, but it's much less efficient, but more flexible.

Comment: Edited my answer giving your a rough example of how to use the reflection method as an alternative. You could build custom methods right into the class itself as well though. So instead of depending on a PropertyChange event, override the class properties to set both values.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Reflection and sample code will look like this

```
public class SomeClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName , object before, object after)
    {
        Type type = this.GetType();
        var val = type.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)?.GetValue(this, null); //Contains changed value 
        if (propertyName == "Name) {
           //Do whatever you want to do with value for "Name"
        }
    }
}
```